# Book for Solr 4.6

Tags: solr

In solr 4.x (I dont know the exact version) there came a modification for the solr.xml. for example in the book Apache Solr 4 Cookbook in chapter one, running solr on jetty, it show a solr.xml file which is not similar to the default solr.xml in solr 4.6. Is there a book which already includes this changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Moving+to+the+New+solr.xml+Format) to view changes between old and new solr.xml, and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond) to get overview of new solr.xml

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the book for the latest version of Solr 4.6. Try this reference guide: http://apache.mirror.quintex.com/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.6.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[Solr in Action](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/books.html#solr-in-action) has a coverage of versions through Solr 4.7